# How do I disable vertical resize when mouse drag on left / right edge?

Tags: 14.04, unity

Currently, when resizing a window by mouseclick + drag on either the left or the right side of the window, it is resized both vertically and horizontally.

I can't find any information about this, not as a feature, not as a setting. Anyone know how to get back the normal behaviour of only horizontal resize?